# Obtaining YouTube Statistics Using JSON (UWP, C#)

Tags: c#, json, youtube, uwp, json.net

been a while since I posted here. I'm working on an app and need to fetch statistics for a particular video using JSON (C#, UWP).

I already have the statistics as a JSON string but can't seem to parse them properly using Newtonsoft. The value always comes back null. This is my code:

```
var url = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?id=" + videoId + "&key=" + cl.googleAPIKey + "&part=snippet,contentDetails,statistics,status";
var http = new HttpClient();
var response = await http.GetStringAsync(url);

var statistics = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Statistics>(response);

string totalViews = statistics.viewCount;
```

The classes generated by Json2CSharp are:

```
public class PageInfo
{
    public int totalResults { get; set; }
    public int resultsPerPage { get; set; }
}

public class Default
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Medium
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class High
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Standard
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Maxres
{
    public string url { get; set; }
    public int width { get; set; }
    public int height { get; set; }
}

public class Thumbnails
{
    public Default @default { get; set; }
    public Medium medium { get; set; }
    public High high { get; set; }
    public Standard standard { get; set; }
    public Maxres maxres { get; set; }
}

public class Localized
{
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
}

public class Snippet
{
    public DateTime publishedAt { get; set; }
    public string channelId { get; set; }
    public string title { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public Thumbnails thumbnails { get; set; }
    public string channelTitle { get; set; }
    public List<string> tags { get; set; }
    public string categoryId { get; set; }
    public string liveBroadcastContent { get; set; }
    public Localized localized { get; set; }
}

public class ContentDetails
{
    public string duration { get; set; }
    public string dimension { get; set; }
    public string definition { get; set; }
    public string caption { get; set; }
    public bool licensedContent { get; set; }
    public string projection { get; set; }
}

public class Status
{
    public string uploadStatus { get; set; }
    public string privacyStatus { get; set; }
    public string license { get; set; }
    public bool embeddable { get; set; }
    public bool publicStatsViewable { get; set; }
}

public class Statistics
{
    public string viewCount { get; set; }
    public string likeCount { get; set; }
    public string dislikeCount { get; set; }
    public string favoriteCount { get; set; }
    public string commentCount { get; set; }
}

public class Item
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public string etag { get; set; }
    public string id { get; set; }
    public Snippet snippet { get; set; }
    public ContentDetails contentDetails { get; set; }
    public Status status { get; set; }
    public Statistics statistics { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public string kind { get; set; }
    public string etag { get; set; }
    public PageInfo pageInfo { get; set; }
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

As I say the value will always come back as null regardless of the video ID.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please post the contents of `response` string as well?

Comment: Sure that the JSON obtained is compatible with your class that you are converting to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are deserializing to the wrong class. *Json2Csharp* generated many classes, but `Statistics` is way down the tree. You should deserialize the `RootObject` instead:

```
var root = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>( response );
```

And then navigate to the statistics within the resulting class structure like for example:

```
foreach ( var statistics in root.Items.Select( i => i.Statistics) )
{
    //do something
}
```

Comment: This works brilliantly, thank you for helping. I will mark this as the correct answer :)

Comment: Great :-). Happy coding!

Comment: Although my code isn't open source, I've included credit to your help in the comments (just to say thanks) :) https://pasteboard.co/H7l1Hhj.png

Comment: That's so nice of you :-)! Thanks!